# Hiding one line on a D3 plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, plot

I have an array of x,y points

```
var plot = [{x:1, y:2}, {x:3, y:4}, {x:5, y:6}, {x:6, y:7}];
```

which I draw using D3 on a svg canvas

```
var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d)
    {
        return d.x;
    })
    .y(function(d)
    {
        return d.y;
    });

lineFunc(plot);
```

The above code will draw *three* lines as I defined *four* points.
How can I hide the second line?

I tried adding a parameter to the points like this:

```
var plot = [{x:1, y:2, show:true}, {x:3, y:4, show:true}, {x:5, y:6, show:false}, {x:6, y:7, show:true}];
```

How can I exploit such boolean to just hide the second line? I.e. the line connecting point `{3,4}` with point `{5,6}`

I tried with

```
var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d)
            {
                return d.x;
            })
            .y(function(d)
            {
                return d.y;
            })      
            .defined(function(d)
            {
                return d.show;
            });
```

but this code doesn't work for me as it hides both the left and right lines belonging to the point `{5,6}`

Comment: I would split up the array into two separate ones and draw the lines separately.

Comment: How exactly? Can you elaborate more in details? Thanks!

Comment: `var plot = [[{x:1, y:2}, {x:3, y:4}], [{x:5, y:6}, {x:6, y:7}]];` and then use [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) as e.g. [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I think your solution deserves a proper answer. I tried it and works perfectly. No need for nested selection

Comment: Happy to put that in an answer, but I wouldn't have expected that to work out of the box :) I guess you haven't posted your full code, but it definitely won't work in every setup. Could you post your code please so I can say why this works in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@LarsKotthoff's comment is probably the sane way to do this, but you could do a little path parsing...

```
var path = svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", function(){
    // d3 generated path
    var p = lineFunc(plot);
    // find all the segments to remove
    plot.filter(function(d){
      return !d.show;
    }).forEach(function(d){
      // replace the "Lx,y" with "Mx,y" - Line to Move
      p = p.replace("L" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y), "M" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y));
    });
    return p;
  })
  .style("fill","none")
  .style("stroke","steelblue")
  .style("stroke-width", 2);
```

Note, this would only work if you are using `linear` interpolation, you'd have to modify for the others.

---

Some working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", 250)
      .attr("height", 250);
      
    var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0,250]).domain([0,10]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([250,0]).domain([0,10]);

    var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.x);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.y);
      });

    var plot = [{
      x: 0,
      y: Math.random() * 10,
      show: true
    }, {
      x: 2,
      y: Math.random() * 10,
      show: true
    }, {
      x: 4,
      y: Math.random() * 10,
      show: true
    }, {
      x: 6,
      y: Math.random() * 10,
      show: true
    }, {
      x: 8,
      y: Math.random() * 10,
      show: false
    }, {
      x: 10,
      y: Math.random() * 10,
      show: true
    }];
    
    var path = svg.append("path")
      .attr("d", function(){
        var p = lineFunc(plot);
        plot.filter(function(d){
          return !d.show;
        }).forEach(function(d){
          p = p.replace("L" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y), "M" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y));
        });
        return p;
      })
      .style("fill","none")
      .style("stroke","steelblue")
      .style("stroke-width", 2);
      
  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```